# Why did my last name came up in Xcode autocomplete?

Tags: xcode

I thought this was a bit weird, but I don't have any properties with my last name or anything else that would even cause this to happen. Here's an image:

[image: My last name in autocomplete]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably grabbed it from the boilerplate comment header at the top of the file.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That's one idea, but the code is commented out. What's even more strange is that it only works on 'self.view'